# Compile a Java file... with a Java program

Tags: java, compilation

Is it possible for a program written in Java to compile a file using the JDK compiler (aside from using Java to open command prompt and throw the "javac" command at it to compile the file)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Java 6 and onwards there is an API to use the compiler.  This might be what you are looking for.

http://www.javabeat.net/2007/04/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html

Note that you need a JDK to have the compiler available.  JRE will not be enough.   If that is a problem consider embedding the Eclipse Java compiler in your application.

Comment: The code at

http://www.javabeat.net/2007/04/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/

throws me a `NullPointerException` :o

Comment: And you use an "java.exe" found in a JDK?

Answer (score 10):

Java 6 has a Compiler API Check out Java Compiler Class Javadoc

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html

and an example

http://www.javabeat.net/2007/04/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/

Answer (score 3):

The Apache Byte Code Engineering Library is your friend.

http://commons.apache.org/bcel/